# OSX terminal giving the message "Python: can't open file '=': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" upon startup

Tags: python, macos, terminal

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do3h6.png)

I have no idea what this message is. It's not exactly hindering my usage of python, but seeing a paragraph every time I open the terminal is unsettling, and i've looked online everywhere for an explanation, but there is none. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: One of your shell startup files (~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile, and ~/.bashrc) has a garbled line (or it might be in another script one of those runs). My guess would be the line is something like `python = something`. Whether that line needs to be fixed or removed or what is something we can't tell without *way* more information.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. For some reason freshman me typed "python = python3". Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if any Python file is executed in your .bash_profile file by typing the following command in terminal:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Hint: lines starting with PATH and export PATH are not being executed and usually are very useful.